# "Change" panel on jframe

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 panels, the first one is the menu, and the second is the application main panel. Firstly the menu panel shows up, than i need to switch to the other panel if a specific button is pressed on the menu (the menu is hidden but the app returns to it after running is completed). && i need to resize the frame too if it's possible.

can i do this somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, this would be a job for a [CardLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), but if you want the frame to resize, you'll have to remove the menu panel from it and add the main panel instead, then call [`pack()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()).

Comment: invalidate() won't resize the frame. pack() must be called on the frame for that.

Comment: i see this solution can work, but i don't know how the panel can access to the frame wihout cardlayout (to access JFrame.pack())

Comment: @bog: um... by holding a reference to it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use card layout.Or else set panel1.setVisible(false) when you want to view Panel2.In the same way set panel2.setVisible(false) when you want to view Panel1.